# Caret package failed to install

Tags: r, r-caret

I am getting this errors trying to install caret package:

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ddalpha’
* removing ‘/home/rspark/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/ddalpha’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ddalpha’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘ddalpha’ is not available for package ‘recipes’
* removing ‘/home/rspark/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/recipes’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘recipes’ is not available for package ‘caret’
* removing ‘/home/rspark/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/caret’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘caret’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any ideas?

```
install.packages("ddalpha")
```

It gives the same error:

```
/usr/lib64/R/library/BH/include/boost/exception/exception.hpp:137: error: expected declaration before end of line
make: *** [AlphaProcedure.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ddalpha’
* removing ‘/home/rspark/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/ddalpha’
```

Comment: Try installing packages `ddalpha` and `recipes` first.

Answer (score 6):

I have found a solution.
I had the same problem. After installing caret with all its dependencies, ddalpha was not installed. Then I tried installing the package ddalpha alone. I got the message:

" There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
        binary source needs_compilation
ddalpha  1.2.1  1.3.1              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: n"

Well, if I anwser yes, it doesn't work. But when I answer no, it does work. It looks like the new version has some problem, but the previous one works fine.

Comment: I experienced the same issue. Saying "n" to wanting to install from sources, strangely enough got around the problem. Caret works (for now).

Comment: Thanks for posting a way out (for now). Saying "n" to install from sources seems to be ok for using caret. Very strange though

Answer (score 4):

As Roman indicated in the comments, `ddalpha` and `recipes` are dependencies that aren't installed yet. You can manually install them as follows:

```
install.packages(c('ddalpha', 'recipes'))
```

Alternatively, you can tell the install.packages() command to grab the necessary packages during the install process.

```
install.packages('caret', dependencies=TRUE)
```

Or list them explicitly:

```
install.packages('caret', dependencies=c('ddalpha', 'recipes'))
```

Or, if you use an IDE such as [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/), the package manager that's included will automatically handle these dependencies for you.

If these suggestions don't solve the problem, you may try updating your instance of R to the latest (3.4.1 as I write this). Also, `ddalpha` is dependent on the [`Rcpp`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) package version 0.11.0 or greater, so you may update that package.

```
update.packages('Rcpp')
```

Comment: The problem is that I have the same error if I try to install the dependencies manually

Comment: See my update. What OS are you using? And are you in native R, or within an IDE?

Comment: I am using a Linux environment on a server, and I updated Rcpp still gives me an error when trying to install ddalpha

Comment: Seeing the specific error messages and code that was used to install would be a big help

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issues, and I had tried almost all the methods mentioned here. But the only one that worked for me was updating my IDE and that sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, running
install.packages('caret', dependencies=TRUE)

from console solved it. I don't know why at the packages window install with "install dependencies" checked didn't work..
R studio: 2022.07.1
R: 3.6.3